# How to call ViewController from project inside project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have in my project another project.

[image]

```
TutorialViewController *con = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialViewController" bundle:nil WithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) AndImages:imageArray PageControlLocation:kPageControlLocationDown WithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self presentModalViewController:con animated:YES];
```

I want to call this `TutorialViewController` `ViewController` but I think (know) that the compiler doesn't find this nib because he doesn't find it in the main bundle...

So does someone know how to call this `VC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the path explicitly via NSBundle class, for example:

```
TutorialViewController *con = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TutorialViewController" bundle:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:File_Name ofType:FILE_TYPE inDirectory:your_directory]] WithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) AndImages:imageArray PageControlLocation:kPageControlLocationDown WithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self presentModalViewController:con animated:YES];
```

If you provide nil to bundle then it will search that file in active project.

For more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: pathForResource:File_Name the name of the Nib? @"TutorialViewController" ofType:FILE_TYPE need to be @"nib" inDirectory:your_directory need to be the directory on my mac?